# How to set a screensaver password in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, screensaver, password-protection

I have a secure position in our company and need to set a password to enter after the screensaver turns on to re-enter the computer.  If I leave my desk for more than a minute I am required to have the screensaver come on...  I can't find where a password is required to resume computer use.  This is a computer used as a server and is never shut off except for updates, etc...

Comment: I have used windows 7 for years and it is not in the same place...

Comment: Take a look, HTH: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/11685-password-protection-wakeup-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html

Comment: @melanie - **It actually is**. The first two options listed by Dude are Windows 7 methods. The third is a Windows 8 only method. There is 4th option enable/disable it through a group policy.

Comment: what is a group policy?  I never used a group policy to apply a screen saver password.